# Entitiy framework and sqlite as file path not working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

I have been trying Browse a sqlite db file and read data using Entity framework .
But following way does not work
I am initiating the MydbContext with sqlite file path 
eg

```
 using (var sourceContext = new MydbContext(@"D:\test\data.sqlite"))
            {
               var a= sourceContext.MyModel.ToList();
            }

  public MydbContext(string path)
           : base(GetConnectionString(path))
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

 public static string GetConnectionString(string path)
        {
var entityConnectionString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                Metadata = "res://*",
                Provider = "System.Data.SQLite.EF6",
                ProviderConnectionString = sqlLiteConnectionString,
            }.ConnectionString;
}
```

Please suggest if there is a proper way to achieve this using sqlite and ef.

Comment: *does not work* Please be more specific.

Comment: Are you experiencing the same problem as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101150/sqlite-ef6-programmatically-set-connection-string-at-runtime ? If so, see that accepted answer there for a solution.

Comment: thanks paul-jan this works.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from comments

```
 private static SQLiteConnection GetConnectionString(string path)
        {
            var con= new SQLiteConnection()
            {
                ConnectionString =
              new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder()
              { DataSource = path, ForeignKeys = true,BinaryGUID = false }
              .ConnectionString
            };

            return con;
        }
```