# SQLite.CodeFirst "The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance."

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to make work the simplest project using [SQLite.CodeFirst](https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst) (1.5.1.25, installed from NuGet package) along with the [System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) (1.0.108, also NuGet). 
However, adding a person will result in

> The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance.

exception. 
Sadly, there are no official example projects to draw inspiration from, so the following is aggregation of dozens of SO answers gets me following minimal example.
The [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101150/sqlite-ef6-programmatically-set-connection-string-at-runtime):

```
class Person
{
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

class MyDBContentext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContentext(string connectionString) 
           : base(new SQLiteConnection() { ConnectionString = connectionString }, true)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDBContentext>(modelBuilder);
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);
    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}

//main
var conStr = $"Data Source=eftest.sqlite;Version=3;Password=123;";
var ctx = new MyDBContentext(conStr);
ctx.People.Add(new Person() { Name = "foo" });//<--- exception throw here
var res = ctx.SaveChanges();
```

and the [App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460357/problems-using-entity-framework-6-and-sqlite):

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)"
           invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"
           description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)"
           type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
            description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
            type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"
          type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite"
          type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

There is also an inner exception (translated, since it ignores thread culture) if it is of any relevance:

> The attempt of method
>   System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderManifest.GetProviderManifestToken(System.String)
>   to access the method
>   System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetSettingValue(System.String,
>   System.String) failed.

Comment: The SQLite.CodeFirst GitHub Repositroy contains an example, using all supported features.
https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst/tree/master/SQLite.CodeFirst.Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling all NuGet packages (SQLite.CodeFirst, System.Data.SQLite and Entity framework) and cleaning the solution resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having this issue in the future, delete all SQLite assemblies from your GAC. In my case, I had to run the followings from a command prompt with admin rights:

```
gacutil –u System.Data.SQLite
gacutil –u System.Data.SQLite.Linq
```