# Enforce foreign key constraint with SQLite & C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I created a foreign key constraint **ON DELETE SET DEFAULT** in the database and I assigned a default value.

What I tried:

- In App.Config: I added "**foreign keys=true;**" to the connectionstring.
- [I edited the dataset XSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj0Nu.png)
- I changed the DataSet on the WinForm and enforced it there: **EnforceConstraints = true**
- I checked, my SQLite version is high enough to support this (I use v1.0.110.0)
- I can't use the PRAGMA command (as shown here: [Enabling Foreign key constraints in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254371/enabling-foreign-key-constraints-in-sqlite)) because the data is bound to controls.
- I rebuilt the project.
- I tried it in SqliteStudio and there the constraint works but in C# it does not.

What could I have possibly missed...

**Update:**
The App.Config was somehow desynched with the project settings thus the extra parameters were not included in the build. However adding the parameter through the project properties throws an error.

```
"Data Source=.\InventoryManagerDatabase.db;foreign keys=true;"
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unknown connection string parameter 'foreign keys'.'

Apparently this parameter does not exist? I checked various resources including [Enabling Foreign key constraints in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254371/enabling-foreign-key-constraints-in-sqlite) & [SQLite EF6 programmatically set connection string at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101150/sqlite-ef6-programmatically-set-connection-string-at-runtime) but that is weird... Did SQLite remove this parameter or rename it?

I also tried (as well as case-sensitivity combinations):

```
EnforceFKConstraints=True;
foreign key=true;
foreign keys=true;
foreign_keys=true;
ForeignKeys=true;
Foreign Key Constraints=true;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; // obviously does not work
```

But nothing works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, finally!

Solution:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\YourDatabaseName.db;Foreign Key Constraints=On;Version=3;"
```

Yeap they somewhere changed it to **Foreign Key Constraints=On** and every page on Google including StackOverflow still show the old parameter...