# sqlite EF DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ef-code-first

I am trying to learn SQLite and entity framework using a simple console application defined below.  When I run this in VS I get the exception shown below when context.SaveChanges() is executed.  I need help in fixing this.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace EntityFrameworkConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sb = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
            sb.DataSource = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "test.db");
            sb.ForeignKeys = true;
            sb.BinaryGUID = true;
            sb.DateTimeFormat = SQLiteDateFormats.ISO8601;
            sb.DateTimeKind = DateTimeKind.Local;
            sb.ToFullPath = true;

            using (var context = new BloggingContext(new SQLiteConnection(sb.ConnectionString)))
            {

                context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Name = "Yet Another Blog #1" });

                context.SaveChanges();

                var blogs = (from b in context.Blogs
                             orderby b.Name
                             select b).ToList();

            }
        }

    }
}

using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EntityFrameworkConsoleApplication1
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyConfiguration))]
    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public BloggingContext(DbConnection c):base(c,true)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace EntityFrameworkConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Data.SQLite.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace EntityFrameworkConsoleApplication1
{
    public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MyConfiguration()
        {
            SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);
            SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);
            Type t = Type.GetType(
                       "System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6");
            FieldInfo fi = t.GetField("Instance", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite", (DbProviderServices)fi.GetValue(null));
        }
    }
}
```

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was unhandled
>   _HResult=-2146233087   _message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.   HResult=-2146233087
>   IsTransient=false   Message=An error occurred while updating the
>   entries. See the inner exception for details.   Source=EntityFramework
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>          at EntityFrameworkConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\EntityFrameworkConsoleApplication1\EntityFrameworkConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line
>   33
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException
>          _HResult=-2146233087
>          _message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>          HResult=-2146233087
>          IsTransient=false
>          Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>          Source=EntityFramework
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.b__2(UpdateTranslator
>   ut)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T
>   noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction, Boolean
>   throwOnClosedConnection)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(Boolean
>   throwOnClosedConnection)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__33()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions
>   options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass28.b__25()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions
>   options)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          InnerException: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException
>               _HResult=-2147467259
>               _message=SQL logic error or missing database no such table: Blogs
>               HResult=-2147467259
>               IsTransient=false
>               Message=SQL logic error or missing database no such table: Blogs
>               Source=System.Data.SQLite
>               ErrorCode=1
>               StackTrace:
>                    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String
>   strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
>                    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
>                    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
>                    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
>                    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd,
>   CommandBehavior behave)
>                    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>                    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>                    at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Reader>b__8()
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1
>   operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1
>   executing, Action`1 executed)
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>                    at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>               InnerException:

Comment: The actual error message is "no such table: Blogs".

Comment: Yes I seen this.  The context does have a local copy of the Blogs before the SaveChanges().  Is this error message saying that the database file, when created does not have the information for Blogs?  I just noticed that the database file is being created before the context is being created.  I had thought that when the context is created the database file is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have changed your model or you have added Blogs after database created since first time.
In Constractor of BloggingContext write this:

```
Database.SetInitializer<BloggingContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BloggingContext>());
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I tried this and get the following exception "DeleteDatabase is not supported by the provider".  I am trying to create and modify the database file in the application.  It was not created previously.

Comment: So why did you got this exception? unless EF has tried to delete something.
if Delete database is not supported by provider, try Migration.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/migration-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I am trying to create the database using code first in the application.  This is an example of an app in which I allow the user to create new databases of items.  The code example above was my attempt of creating a new database file using code first and then to add items to it.  Given the error I am getting I must be doing something incorrectly in the code.  Is it possible to accomplish creating the database using code first and then adding items to it?

Comment: Yes.
I had similar problem before. Because of this i said maybe you changed your model, even a tiny change in the names. So if it was the first time that you ran you progrom, the problem in somewhere else. Instead of "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges" use "DropCreateDatabaseAlways"

Comment: Add this assembly:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.Schema;
and the above of Blog class write this. [Table("Blogs")]
Above BlogId write this: [Key]
Set Breakpoint on DataBase.SetInitializer<>..
Run the progrom. At Breakpoint --> F10 --> right click on DataBase word --> QuickWatch. Find the Connection string. Maybe it's different than what you gave it.

Comment: ILOVECSHARP, thanks for providing feedback but I am still having problems.  "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" causes the same exception as before "Delete Database is not supported by the provider".  Do I have the following correct when creating the database?

Comment: Do I have the beginning of the Main function correct where I create a connection string then a SQLiteConnection and then pass this connection into my context constructor?

Comment: I added the data annotations and viewed the connection string.  The connection string looks correct.

Comment: You're welcome.
Take a look at this: http://www.bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html And read comments.
Seems SQlite provider doesn't support creating database for older versions of EF. One guy who left a comment there had similar exception.
And this: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=23616
and this post may be helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460357/problems-using-entity-framework-6-and-sqlite

Comment: Yes, what you did for Connection String is correct.