# SQLite 1.0.102.0 and EF6 db-first deploy failed

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6

My develop machine is 64-bit OS, x64 based processor running Windows 10.
I use VS2015 professional and SQLite(v1.0.102.0) develop a simple CRUD program.
here're my steps:

1. use Install-Package System.Data.SQLite install Sqlite things on my project.
2. app.config as below:

   ```
   <entityFramework>
       <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
            </parameters>
       </defaultConnectionFactory>
       <providers>
           <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
           <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
       </providers>
   </entityFramework>
   <system.data>
       <DbProviderFactories>
           <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
           <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
           <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
           <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
       </DbProviderFactories>
   </system.data>
   ```
3. Then I use some Sqlite tool create a database & tables.
4. Use EF Db-Frist mapped to this database.
5. Add CRUD codes.
6. **Project platform set to x86**
7. Debug, everything worked.

THEN, i copy all files in x86\Released to another machine:

- 64-bit OS, x64 based processor.
- Windows 10 clean.
- NET 4.6
- Nothing installed.

Program not work: *The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6' could not be loaded...blah blah blah...*

believe me I've wasted long time on searched for answer and and changed many settings in app.config, NOT WORK.

I hope some one has same problem and once solved please give me the simple directly way. Thanks.

**Things I already did**

- Manually download SQLite from [system.data.sqlite download page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) and install *Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.6)*, only this version can use design-time component.
- Followed [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460357/problems-using-entity-framework-6-and-sqlite) add a new provider, now work.
- People said don't use NUGET, I trusted and followed, not work either.

Comment: I was comparing with my project with exact setup. I found that your app.config was missing this `<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />` I can not assure whether this resolve the issue, but better give a try.

Comment: I always use nuget and create a wix installer for deployment.  i have never had a problem.  never had to install anything else on a client machine.

Comment: I distribute these dlls `INSTALLDIR\EntityFramework.dll`
`INSTALLDIR\System.Data.SQLite.dll`
`INSTALLDIR\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll`
`INSTALLDIR\System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll`
`INSTALLDIR\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll`
`INSTALLDIR\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll`