# EF6, SQLite won't work without App.config

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to make a plug in that will use EF6.1 and SQLite for an app where I can't change the App.config so all the configuration and connection string needs to be set in code.

I found this answer that looked promising [Problems using Entity Framework 6 and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460357/problems-using-entity-framework-6-and-sqlite?rq=1)

So now I have a configuration class like this:

```
public class CollectionDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public CollectionDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite"(DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices)));
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);                 
    }
}
```

I have confirmed this gets hit before the context is created for the first time and all these return values.

My context looks like this

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString)
    :   base(connectionString) { }

    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }      
}
```

And I have some code calling it like this:

```
var context = new MyContext("Data Source = mytest.db; Version = 3;");
var entities = context.MyEntities.ToList();
```

When I try and run the code it looks like the context is assuming the connection string is for SQL Server as it gives me:

Keyword not supported: 'version'.

If I remove it I then get an error that it cannot connect and its clearly trying to connect to a SQL Server database.

I tried passing in a SQLite connection by adding a constructor:

```
public MyContext(DbConnection connection) 
    : base(connection, contextOwnsConnection: true)
{ }
```

And calling it with this:

```
var context = new MyContext(new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = mytest.db; Version = 3;"));
var entities = context.MyEntities.ToList();
```

But then I get the error:

Unable to determine the DbProviderFactory type for connection of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

So I made a factory resolver and registered that

```
public class FactoryResolver : IDbProviderFactoryResolver
{
    public DbProviderFactory ResolveProviderFactory(DbConnection connection)
    {
        if (connection.GetType() == typeof(SQLiteConnection))
        {
            return SQLiteFactory.Instance;
        }

        if (connection.GetType() == typeof(EntityConnection))
        {
            return SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And added:

```
SetProviderFactoryResolver(new FactoryResolver());
```

but now I get this:

No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

I've beet at this for two days now and I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The minimum needed to make the constructor with connection string working is a custom `IProviderInvariantName`, `IDbDependencyResolver` and `DbConfiguration`:

```
public class SQLiteProviderInvariantName : IProviderInvariantName
{
    public static readonly SQLiteProviderInvariantName Instance = new SQLiteProviderInvariantName();
    private SQLiteProviderInvariantName() { }
    public const string ProviderName = "System.Data.SQLite.EF6";
    public string Name { get { return ProviderName; } }
}

class SQLiteDbDependencyResolver : IDbDependencyResolver
{
    public object GetService(Type type, object key)
    {
        if (type == typeof(IProviderInvariantName)) return SQLiteProviderInvariantName.Instance;
        if (type == typeof(DbProviderFactory)) return SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance;
        return SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type type, object key)
    {
        var service = GetService(type, key);
        if (service != null) yield return service;
    }
}

class SQLiteDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public SQLiteDbConfiguration()
    {
        AddDependencyResolver(new SQLiteDbDependencyResolver());
    }
}
```

Now this should work:

```
var context = new MyContext("Data Source = mytest.db; Version = 3;");
var entities = context.MyEntities.ToList();
```

**Update:** For NET4.0 you would also need a custom `IDbProviderFactoryResolver`:

```
class SQLiteDbProviderFactoryResolver : IDbProviderFactoryResolver
{
    public static readonly SQLiteDbProviderFactoryResolver Instance = new SQLiteDbProviderFactoryResolver();
    private SQLiteDbProviderFactoryResolver() { }
    public DbProviderFactory ResolveProviderFactory(DbConnection connection)
    {
        if (connection is SQLiteConnection) return SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance;
        if (connection is EntityConnection) return EntityProviderFactory.Instance;
        return null;
    }
}
```

and add

```
if (type == typeof(IDbProviderFactoryResolver)) return SQLiteDbProviderFactoryResolver.Instance;
```

to the `SQLiteDbDependencyResolver.GetService` method implementation.

Comment: I gave this a try but now I get the error message: Unable to determine the DbProviderFactory type for connection of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

Comment: That's strange because I was able to duplicate the issue exactly the way you described it, and then the above fixed it. Make sure there is no other `DbConfiguration` classes inside the project (for instance, the one you used in the posted code) and resolvers - just the classes from the answer. And that you use the constructor with the connection string, not with connection. As you can see, the above `IDbDependencyResolver` brute force resolves the `DbProviderFactory`, so shouldn't be getting such error.

Comment: If you can provide full repro project, I can take a look at it, but I believe this is the solution, because I was able to connect/work with SQLite database with explicitly commenting out the SQLite related enties from App.config, and keeping the localdb default, SqlServer and MySQL

Comment: Brilliant, that worked, thanks. I had tried a custom IDbProviderFactoryResolver but I wasn't returning the right types for the right DbConnection type so it was failing.

Comment: You are welcome. The repro project helped a lot - my test (NET4.6) was using `DefaultDbProviderFactoryResolver` and yours - `Net40DefaultDbProviderFactoryResolver` which seem to use different code paths - the former uses simply `connection.ProviderFactory` and the latter - config file :(